# Rsync with delete option doesn't seem to work

Tags: jenkins, rsync

I have this command line :
rsync -Cr --delete Website /Users/Jenkins/front-end/

Because of the flag I expected to have the files deleted in front-end/ is they're not anymore in Website, right ?

But it seems like I was wrong, is there any decent way to do that ?
Or do I have to rm -rf front-end before rsync (which renders rsync less effective)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a recent version of rsync that works the same as on my machine, your command should work. Here's a test example:

```
> mkdir -p site/a
> touch site/a/b.txt
> rsync -Cr --delete site/ site2
> find site2
site2
site2/a
site2/a/b.txt
> rm site/a/b.txt
> rsync -Cr --delete site/ site2
> find site2
site2
site2/a
```

I suggest you verify a bit more your setup. You might want to test with the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're absolutly right .. my problem wasn't here at all.
Git was my problem I forgot the -u option to git add.
Thanks a lot anyway !